# Manual crop in Image Transforms

Tags: image-transforms

I would like to **manually crop the image transforms** for an uploaded image.

I know there are crop plugins for Craft ([image-resizer](https://github.com/engram-design/ImageResizer), [AviaryImageEditor](https://github.com/fruitstudios/AviaryImageEditor)), but these plugins crop the original image and **not** the image transforms..

I'm looking for something very similar to the [manual crop module in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop).

So you can upload one image, afterwards you manually crop the different image styles / image transforms..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a plugin like this for Craft. But this solution does a similar thing. Maybee it works for you: [Let clients set crop position for images](https://craftcookbook.net/recipes/simple-way-to-let-clients-set-crop-position-for-images). 
Otherwise you could also take a look on the focuspoint plugin: https://github.com/smcyr/Craft-FocusPoint

Comment: Thanks Tom, although this workararound is not perfect, it will do in most situations.